# Half-circle, transparent cutout from bordered div with gradient background

Tags: html, css

I would like to accomplish the following graphic style with CSS:

[image: node-gui-concept]

---

I've been able to successfully replicate (approach) every single aspect of the intended design, except for the half-circle cutouts.

The closest I've been able to get is masking out the parts of the node body by setting a `background-color` for the cutout circles matching that of the backdrop, as well as inset shadows and border on the corresponding side.

After that, I added an extension towards the opposite direction, so that any shadow cast by the node is also effectively masked out. These are the results:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

/* --- cutout --- */

.node-cutout-left {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  left: -1px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 36px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  
  border: 1px solid rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05) inset;
}

.node-cutout-left::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -18px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

/* --- end of cutout --- */

.node {
  cursor: move;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border: 1px solid rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
}

.node-header {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-color: #489ddb;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 100;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #489ddb; /* overlay node-border */
}

.node-body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(170deg,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);

  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="node" draggable="true" ondragstart="console.log(event);">
  <div class="node-header">
    <div class="node-title">Gain</div>
  </div>
  <div class="node-body">
    <div class="node-cutout-left" style="top:20px;"></div>
    <div class="node-cutout-left" style="top:70px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I need **transparent** background in the masked out area. How could I accomplish this?

---

I've also prepared a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu2xb66f/1/) (illustrating the problem) for those who'd wish to join this brainstorm, and whose help I would appreciate beyond measure.

Questions already on SO failed to solve my issue so far, as they use either the box-shadow of the element used as the cutout to fill the rendered area of the clipped element (which would cancel out the gradient background in my case)...

... or SVG clips, for which I -- for the life of it -- can't find a working example when applied to HTML elements with bordered style.

Comment: Given that you have said the existing solutions aren't feasible for you I suspect you've painted yourself into a design corner. My only suggestion is to use an SVG element for the container...

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, since I'm pretty much cornered with this, I think I might need to resort to an SVG solution. If you have one in your stock, please don't hesitate to share it, I... well, I wouldn't say I'm familiar with SVG. Either way, I greatly appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: I confess I'm still getting to grips with SVG but when it comes to custom shapes, quite often the simplest answer is to fire up Illustrator or Sketch, create the element as an SVG and export it out as an SVG element instead of an image.

Comment: In theory, clipping would give you the desired effect: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/, but I'm having a hard time making even a simple example work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here you are. Probably it can be achieved in less code, but it's a start.

Only the gradient is a small issue..

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  background-color: #ccc;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.node {
  cursor: move;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 60px;
  width: 180px;
}

.node-header {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-color: #489ddb;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.node-body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 19px;
}

.node-content {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(170deg, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  min-height: 145px;
}

.node-cutout {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:200px;
}

.node-square {
  position: absolute;  
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
  width: 19px;
  height: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:#eaeaea;
}


.round {
  padding: 18px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
}

.round:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200px #eaeaea;
  z-index: 1
}

.round:after {
  background-color: rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width:1px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.round.top:after {
  margin-top: -18px;
}

.round.top:before {
  left: -18px;
}

.round.bottom:before {
  left: -18px;
  top: -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="node" draggable="true" ondragstart="console.log(event);">
  <div class="node-header">
    <div class="node-title">Gain</div>
  </div>
  <div class="node-body">
    <div class="node-content">
    </div>
    <div class="node-cutout">
      <div class="node-cutout-left" style="">
        <span class="round top"></span>
        <span class="round bottom"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="node-cutout-left" style="margin-top:-17px;">
        <span class="round top"></span>
        <span class="round bottom"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="node-square">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good approach, but in essence this is the same as just a single circle with box-shadow to fill the relevant (left) parts of `.node`.

Comment: Do you have an example in which way this is the same, or could you tell me why isn't this answering your question?

Comment: Well, you said it yourself: _"Only the gradient is a small issue"_.

Comment: Yes I know. That part was taking too much time. I didn't know if this was a big deal for you so I thought maybe you could ignore the gradient at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an essential part. Either way, I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:

```
<div class="node" draggable="true" ondragstart="console.log(event);">
  <div class="node-header">
    <div class="node-title">Gain</div>
  </div>
  <div class="node-body">
  <i class="fa fa-volume-up fa_custom"></i>
    <div class="node-cutout-left" style="top:20px;"></div>
    <div class="node-cutout-left" style="top:70px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";

}
.fa_custom{position: absolute;
    left: -11px;
    z-index: 1000000;
    color: #fff;
    top: 32px;}
.node {
  cursor: move;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 60px;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.node-header {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-color: #489ddb;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.node-body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background: #ffffff;



}

.node-cutout-left {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  left: -1px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 36px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;

  border: 1px solid rgba(122, 167, 200, 0.7);
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05) inset;
}

.node-cutout-left::after {
     content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -19px;
    top: 3px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 33px;
    border-radius: 64%;
    background-color: #489DDB;
}
```

JSFiddle Link:  `https://jsfiddle.net/jdqht5ch/`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have everything taken care of, except for the cutouts. What I've provided above is a [mcve]. Unfortunately, your answer [does not solve](https://jsfiddle.net/jdqht5ch/1/) the issue.